# MariaDB Galera cluster SST sync from specified donor is impossible

Tags: galera

Galera cluster documentation states that you can use preferred donor in galera cluster, as rsync SST is blocking, thus you can prefer less used node:

https://galeracluster.com/library/documentation/mysql-wsrep-options.html#wsrep-sst-donor

but in conf file, providing donor parameter like this:

```
wsrep_sst_donor="192.168.0.33,192.168.0.32"
```

gives an error like this:

```
db4 mariadbd[14970]: ... 0 [Warning] WSREP: Member 4.0 (db4) requested state transfer from '192.168.0.33', but it is impossible to select State Transfer donor: No route to host
```

ping destination host works without any problem, no network issues at all.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is little bit shy. If an example would be provided, this would be clear from the beginning. The issue is, that galera cluster threats `wsrep_sst_donor` as text and tries to resolve literal IP address to network IP address, and this "IP-host" does not resolve.

Use galera cluster node name to the value, like this:

```
wsrep_sst_donor="db3,db2"
```

Then it works ok:

```
db4 mariadbd[17621]: ... 0 [Note] WSREP: Member 4.0 (db4) requested state transfer from 'db3,db2'. Selected 1.0 (db3)(SYNCED) as donor.
db4 mariadbd[17621]: ... 0 [Note] WSREP: Shifting PRIMARY -> JOINER (TO: 1874846)
```